# How to get all results where column is larger then zero in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, html, google-chrome

I have created a table in SQLite Chrome (html5):

```
transaction.executeSql(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS record('+
            'id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,'+
            'fkindicatorspeciesid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES indicatorspecies(indicatorspeciesid),'+
            'latitude INTEGER NOT NULL,'+
            'longitude INTEGER NOT NULL,'+
            'time TEXT NOT NULL,'+
            '`when` TEXT NOT NULL,'+
            'numberseen INTEGER NOT NULL,'+
            'notes TEXT NOT NULL,'+
            'online_recordid INTEGER,'+
            'status TEXT,'+
            'locationid INTEGER REFERENCES location(locationid),'+
            'surveyid INTEGER REFERENCES survey(id));',
            [], nullHandler,errorHandler);
```

Then I add some data to it:
[image]

Now I try to retrieve all the records where 'online_recordid' is larger then zero:

```
select * from record where online_recordid > 0;
```

I should not get my record back because there is nothing in the column 'online_recordid'. The problem is that I do get the record back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I eventually solved it.

```
select * from record where online_recordid <> '' and online_recordid > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

You can validly store '' (empty string) into online_recordid, **EVEN IF** it is defined as "INTEGER".  That affects only `Type Affinity` and does not restrict the data in any way unlike a traditional RDBMS.

What has most likely happened is that your code is inserting '' into `online_recordid` when what you really wanted to store was NULL.

When the query `online_recordid > 0` fires, the blank is converted into [something] that makes it `>0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see that online_recordid is not null:

```
select * from record where online_recordid > 0 and online_recordid is not null
```

However, the behavior is strange. I tried doing the same query as you, but I get no records back. Maybe I did something different than you.

Comment: I tried your line but got records back that did not have any online_recordid. I Think that probably something happened as explained by cyberkiwi.